# Plain text e-mails in Dark Mode Mail 12

Tags: mail.app, email

I regularly deal with e-mails from a company using SalesForce where the messages are sent with a bright white background for the entire message body, set in the HTML.

In Dark Mode this is exceptionally uncomfortable, as you'll be ticking through your e-mails reading white on black, when suddenly you're hit with an almost full screen of white.

I checked the raw message contents and I do see that there are two parts, an HTML version and a plain-text version. However, I cannot find the configuration option to specify that I want Mail to render the plain text version of the message. So how can I do this, or otherwise override the colours of these messages?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in Mail, maybe in Outlook or another client.

Comment: @TomGewecke I don't have any choice but to use Mail. I have discovered some AppleScript APIs that might enable what I want but it's pretty horrendous to implement.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Terminal command to generally prefer plain text E-Mails over rich format. However, I haven't tested it under Catalina.

```
defaults write com.apple.mail PreferPlainText -bool TRUE
```

Comment: I tried this, however unfortunately it has no effect. Further research suggested this config is no longer honoured since some new version of Mail.